# Как передать string через props в рекурсию

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть компонент `Tree.vue`

```
 <p class="tree-list">
      <node-tree :text="'/catalog/applicabilities/edit?id='" 
      v-for="item in treeData" :node="item" :key="item.id" ></node-tree>
  </p>
```

Который передаёт пропс в `NodeTree.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="node-tree">

    <a :href="url + node.id" class="label font-weight-bold" :myid="node.id" :myname="node.name">{{ node.name }} {{url}}</a>

    <a  v-if="node.children && node.children.length" v-b-toggle="node.id.toString()"  class="dropicn m-1 font-weight-bold"> > </a>
    <!-- Element to collapse -->
    <b-collapse :id="node.id.toString()">
     <ul> <node1 v-for="child in node.children" :node="child" :key="child.id"></node1> </ul>
    </b-collapse>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "node1",
  props: {
    text: String,
    node: Object,
  },    
  data() {
    return {    
      url: ''
    }
  },      
  mounted() {
    let xxx='';
    if(this.url===''){
      xxx = this.text+' test'
      this.url=xxx         
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

В итоге, получается, что  `{{url}}` корректно отображается только в родителях, а в детях получаю такое вот `Имя undefined test`. Если url передавать не пропсом, а сразу назначать в `NodeTree.vue` то всё работает корректно.

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли в дочернем компоненте в хуке created на this.text

Comment: console.log('created ',this.text) выводит это created  undefined

Comment: Created это функция должна быть, как mounted только created, вот там и выведите в консоль this.text

Comment: я понимаю, консолю в NodeTree.vue в хуке created() вот это console.log('created ',this.text), и получаю кучу вывода с created  /catalog/applicabilities/edit?id= и created  undefined

Comment: скрин: https://radikal.ru/big/3cqfz2u91w69h

Comment: Попробуй передавать пропс не так :text="'/catalog/applicabilities/edit?id='" , а так text="/catalog/applicabilities/edit?id="

Comment: <node-tree   v-for="item in treeData" :node="item" :key="item.id" text="/catalog/applicabilities/edit?id=" ></node-tree> передал, всё тоже самое андефаинт

Answer (score 0):

Решение было очевидным, нужно было каждый раз передавать пропс себе же.

```
<node1 v-for="child in node.children" :node="child" :key="child.id" :url="url"></node1
```